# Twitter bootstrap a href popover not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-content="This is the body of Popover" data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop</a>
```

and the javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').popover();
});
```

and I have included the below Js files:

```
src="jquery.min.js"
src="bootstrap.js"
src="Tooltip.js"
src="Popover.js"
```

but when I click the link nothing happens but it seems to be reloading the page.

FYI, this button popover code works fine but the a href popover is not working:

```
<button popover="Some text" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="btn btn-default">Scope</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/j5T3t/, why are you including  Tooltip.js and Popover.js and not the full?

Comment: Actually I tried with & without tooltip.js & popover.js files but its not working either.

Comment: Any error in the console? Or 404 in network tab? You have only this code or something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not too sure what you're attempting but this is a working pop!

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexHighHigh/weuWk/1785/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover">pop</a>
```

**JS**

```
$("#example").popover({ title: 'This is the body of pop'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but its not working for me. Do we need to include any other js files?

Comment: If you navigate to the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/AlexHighHigh/weuWk/1785/) does it pop when you hover?

Comment: Yes, jsfiddle works for me but when I use this in my code its not working. Actually I am using angular-ui-bootstrap.js and  bootstrap.js as well in my code base do you think there is a conflict between these two?.

Comment: can you please put your code into JSfiddle so we can play with the live environment and test there, if you have a second?

Comment: Its working fine individually but when I put the popover inside the angularjs ng-repeat its not working. Any idea?

Comment: Inside the ng-repeat I used ng-click to call JS script and it works now.

Comment: Glad to hear, best of luck with the project! :)